# How to make teaser from string in golang?

Tags: string, go

I'd like to make teaser by cutting first few words (divided by spaces) from arbitrary utf8 input string `content`. 
What I came up with is this:

```
runes := []rune(content)
teaser := string(runes[0:75])
```

The problem is that the above code cuts words in the middle. What I want is to cut at the end of (say tenth) word, in order to make pretty teasers.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: That depends on what you consider a word boundary: Look through the runes counting words (i.e. word boundaries), possibly skipping other stuff and stop once you run out of runes or have gathered enough words. This will still produce dead ugly input for anything in real life.

Comment: Well, the word boundaries are spaces, i.e. `'   '` .  Not sure how to follow the rest of your tips.

Comment: If you just want to split on unicode spaces, what's wrong with [`strings.Fields`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields)?

Comment: @JimB I din't `just want to split string`. I want to make a teaser out of it. Don't know how to do so, and don't care with what function.

Comment: Except when not. Hypens---at least in proper typesetting---delimit words but arn't surrounded by spaces. Snd there is a shitload if different types of spaces. SO good luck. The fun starts when you've got RTL text embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func teaser(s string, wordCount int) string {
    words := strings.Fields(s)

    if len(words) < wordCount {
        wordCount = len(words)
    }

    return strings.Join(words[:wordCount], " ")
}
```

... where `s` is your full string, and `wordCount` the number of words to include.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/47TfI50wh8n)

Comment: Works great. Thanks!